# Tag manager jquery separador de tags

Tags: jquery, yii

desde um tempo para cá, o meu tag manager, no yii framework, está gerando tags tendo como separador de tags um "?", ao invés de uma virgula, o que pode ser?

Código:

```
$('.tm-input').tagsManager({
    prefilled: ["<?php echo $model->tags ?>"],
    tagsContainer: '.tags-show',
    CapitalizeFirstLetter: true,
    preventSubmitOnEnter: true,
    typeahead: true,
    delimeters: [680, 188, 13],
    backspace: [8],
    blinkBGColor_1: '#CDE69C',
    blinkBGColor_2: '#CDE69C',
    hiddenTagListName: 'hiddenTagListA',
    hiddenTagListId: "Node_tags"

});

jQuery(".tm-input").on('tm:refresh', function (e, taglist) {
    $("#Node_tags").val(taglist); //isto faz com que ele pegue no node_tags e insira as tags do html dentro do taglist do php
});
```

Form:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'tags'); ?>

            <!--- Criei este input em html para este ser preencido enquanto o que está em php vai receber os valores deste -->
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $model->tags ?>" id="taggenerator" class="tm-input form-control" placeholder="Insira tags aqui..."/>
            <?php echo $form->error($model, 'tags'); ?>



            <div class="col-lg-12 tags-show">
                <!---Este é o hidden field que vai receber e enviar para a db os valores do input-->
                <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'tags'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

EDIT:
Quando faço as tags, o resultado é este:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde aparecem os "?"? Pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: Editei a pergunta com a resposta à sua pergunta! 
Obrigado ! :)

Comment: Já olhou o código fonte pra ver o que aparece em `prefilled: ["<?php echo $model->tags ?>"],`?

Comment: Vi sim, aparecem as tags separadas pelo ponto de interrogação, porque é isso que é inserido, o prefilled simplesmente serve para preencher automaticamente caso seja feito um update.

Mas descobri que o erro está nos delimiters, colocando os valores originais:
        delimiters: [9, 13, 44], volta a aparecer a virgula.

Comment: Mas o problema é que coclocando os valores assim, a minha tag, quando faço update da mesma, não aparecem as tags todas, mas sim só a primeira tag...